# towlower() return "?" instead of this character in lower register

Tags: c

it is simple version just for ask, i have this program

```
wchar_t c;
wprintf(L"input\n");
wscanf(L"%d", &c);
wprintf(L"output\n");
wprintf(L"%lc", towlower(c));
```

and this input/output
[image]

if i input "W" there output "?", with another characters i have the same situation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin in your link question and answer about string, functions there returns pointer. I just need for this character

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But function for string would work?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i use towlower, look at. But i understand you, thanks

Comment: My bad -- sorry, I'm getting old. I missed the `'w'`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And it still won't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the line `wscanf(L"%d", &c);`, you passed `%d` as format specifier. So `wscanf()` is searching for an integer, but you are passing a character instead. Changing to `%c` will solve it.

See the specification in the `wscanf(3)` manpage:

```
   d       Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same
           as expected for the subject sequence of wcstol() with the value 10 for
           the  base argument. In the absence of a size modifier, the application
           shall ensure that the corresponding argument is a pointer to int.

           ...

   c       Matches  a sequence of wide characters of exactly the number specified
           by the field width (1 if no field width is present in  the  conversion
           specification).
```

Comment: ‍♂️ Really, not right specifier. My bad. And for future, if it wprintf/wcanf there are for %c and %s different specifiers. Should be %lc and %ls. Thanks